# Preciso fazer testes unitários das entidades do sistema?

Tags: java, testes, pojo, java-bean

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e participo de uma equipe , a nós foi dada a tarefa de  fazer uma série de testes com um sistema,`testes de integração continua`, `testes unitários` ....
A questão é que todos os sistemas possuem classes de entidades e regras de negócios.  Assim ,é muito interessante testar as classes de regras de negócios.
Minhas classes de entidade possuem apenas o de sempre:

```
atributos  
getters() and setters()   
construtor()  
toString()  
equals()   
hashcode()  
compareTo()
```

Mas tenho uma duvida em relação as classes de entidade:
Eu devo fazer `testes unitários` para as minhas classes de entidade(beans ou pojos) já que elas não possuem nenhuma regra de negócio?

Comment: Existe comportamento nas suas entidades (além de `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString`)? Só você pode dizer se testes são necessários nessa camada, porém a reposta para uma aplicação desenvolvida seguindo princípios DDD provavelmente será bem diferente da resposta para uma aplicação com um modelo mais anêmico. Teste o que agregar valor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não se faz teste unitário de getters e setters, que são os métodos contidos em POJOS. Já para qualquer outro método deve-se criar os testes unitários. É bom ter em mente que a ideia de um teste unitário é que a sua execução pode resultar falha caso haja uma alteração na classe/método alvo do teste. Dessa forma não faz sentido testar POJOs pois os seus métodos são apenas de recuperação e modificação por padrão, muitas vezes gerados automaticamente inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Como disse a Giuliana Bezerra não faz sentido testar getters/setters. O mesmo se aplica para para o equals(), hashCode() etc. Os métodos que devem ter seu comportamento testado são aqueles que envolvem regras de negociais e cuja mudança pode impactar na evolução do sistema - para se evitar a regressão. Testar getters/setters não acrescenta nada a sua suite de teste.

Na hora de decidir se um teste unitário deve ser escrito sugiro pensar em alguns pontos:

1. Qual a complexidade do método/classe em questão?
2. Qual a importância do método/classe no módulo/sistema/aplicação? (i.e: quantas classes dependem daquele código - esse é um indicativo de que aquele código pode vir a ser um ponto de falha crucial no sistema)
3. Qual a possibilidade de aquele código sofrer manutenção no futuro? (manutenção significa mudança de código e para que esta seja mais segura, nada melhor do que ter testes que assegurem o funcionamento. Quanto mais testes, menos medo temos de mudar um código)

PS.: acho estranho essas suas entidades só terem esses tipos de métodos. Lembre-se que a orientação a objeto envolve atributos e comportamentos. Acho, sem conhecer muito da estrutura do seu projeto, que talvez as suas classes devam ser repensadas. Sugiro a leitura do [artigo do Martin Fowler sobre o Modelo Anêmico](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) para saber um pouco mais.